# Switchere s2s API Call returns error 404 no matter what I send

Tags: rest, httprequest, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I am tring to send a POST request to the s2s API endpoint of switchere (https://api.switcherepay.com/post) , following the Documentation provided here : https://developer.switchere.com/api-v2/endpoints/s2s/.

I am getting a 404 error with this repsonse :

```json
{
    "result": "ERROR",
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_message": "Route or parameters is not supported",
    "errors": []
}
```

This is the request I am sending, following the guide of the documentation. For security reasons all fields containing personal information are replaced with xxxxx.

```json
{
  "action": "SALE",
  "client_key": "xxxxxx",
  "card_cvv2": "123",
  "card_number": "4111111111111111",
  "card_exp_month": "01",
  "card_exp_year": "2025",
  "order_id": "xxxxxx",
  "order_amount": 49.99,
  "order_currency": "EUR",
  "order_description": "xxxxxxx",
  "payer_first_name": "John",
  "payer_last_name": "Smith",
  "payer_birth_date": "xxxx-xx-xx",
  "payer_address": "123 Main St",
  "payer_country": "US",
  "payer_state": "NY",
  "payer_city": "New York",
  "payer_zip": "10001",
  "payer_email": "example@example.com",
  "payer_phone": "xxxxxxx",
  "payer_ip": "xxx.xxx.x.x", 
  "term_url_3ds": "https://example.com",
  "hash": "xxxxxxxx"
}
```

I am expecting my request to proceed, or at least get a relevant error on invalid fields or credentials. I am really troubled by the fact that I am getting an error 404 response. Doesn't that mean that the endpoint URL is wrong?

Comment: The docs are _not_ correct; for example the doc for the public endpoint status indicates: https://switchere.com/api/v2/partner/healthcheck, which requires authentication. I'm _guessing_ that the endpoint is actually incorrect - you would need to confirm with them.

Comment: Close enough actually. They expected a different type of request despite not stating it anywhere in their documentation. The endpoint was surprisingly correct

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questiion in case anyone else faces the same issue. The request must be sent as : application/x-www-form-urlencoded and not Json.

This is not stated anywhere on the documentation, at least until now.